# OnClick method on EditText makes app crash

Tags: android, onclick, android-edittext

I have encountered that my application stops when EditText tag is clicked which has OnClick method attached to it that calls new activity.
Here it is in layout :

```
        <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:onClick="LaunchMap"
        android:hint="Vieta"
        android:layout_below="@+id/end_date"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/end_date"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/end_date"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:editable="false"/>
```

And then in my activity class `Main2Activity.java`

```
   public void LaunchMap(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MapsActivity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And logcat information:

```
    05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.rimvydas.projektas, PID: 14898
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method LaunchMap(View) in the activity class android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintContextWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText with id 'location'
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3844)
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4472)
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18779)
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: LaunchMap [class android.view.View]
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:864)
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3837)
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4472) 
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18779) 
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) 
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333) 
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829) 
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) 
05-15 22:47:51.400 14898-14898/com.example.rimvydas.projektas E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Wierd thing is.. if I put this same OnClick method `LaunchMap` on lets say button, it works fine.. So how do I call OnClick on EditText field?

Comment: Can you show your all Main2Activity class codes?

Comment: sure, http://pastebin.com/Y4fRxvRW

Comment: I would recommend to use [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a compiler error and your compiler can not link your method name "LaunchMap" from XML file to mainActivity. I suggest you to change the method name, save project, use new name in XML file and Run your project again.
On the other hand you can use onClickListener programmatically like this:

```
location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LunchMap();
        }
    });
```

if you want to make it programmatically you should remove input parameter View from your method LunchMap

Comment: Thanks, onClickListener  helped.

Answer (score 1):

Check the xlm text version of your layout just before run. I have a similar problem, with Android Studio changing automatically (for a reason I ignore) the onClick reference from "methodName" to "methodName (ActivityName), causing the app to stop.

In your case, it would be changed from "LaunchMap" to "LaunchMap (MainActivity)" for instance, if the method is defined in the MainActivity.